# Slow performance react-use-gesture and react-spring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draggable, react-spring, react-use-gesture

Drag examples in the docs such as [this one](https://use-gesture.netlify.app/docs/extras/) are extremely fast and map very accurately to my finger position. I've tried copying the examples one-to-one but there is a clear lag to catch up with my finger position.

[Here is a code sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-gesture-basic-swipe-q47gf?file=/src/App.js:413-476) which has a clear lag when testing on a real device.

**Information:**

- React Use Gesture version: (I've tried all manner of combinations of versions with no impact but this is the configuration in the codesandbox)

```
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "react-spring": "9.1.2",
    "react-use-gesture": "9.1.3"
```

- Device: IPhone 12 pro max
- OS: [e.g. iOS14.5.1]
- Browser chrome

```
function PullRelease() {
  const [{ x }, api] = useSpring(() => ({ x: 0 }));
  const bind = useDrag(({ movement: [mx], down }) =>
    api.start({ x: down ? mx : 0 })
  );
  return (
    <animated.div {...bind()} style={{ padding: 40, background: "gold", x }}>
      Hello World
    </animated.div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I combed through the [source code of the examples](https://github.com/pmndrs/use-gesture/blob/v8/documentation/pages/docs/code/examples.js). The issue was in fact with react-spring, I needed to supply `immediate: true` while the touch is active.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-gesture-basic-swipe-immediate-6bje9?file=/src/App.js

```
function PullRelease() {
  const [{ x }, api] = useSpring(() => ({ x: 0 }));
  const bind = useDrag(({ movement: [mx], down }) =>
    api.start({ x: down ? mx : 0, 
        immediate: down // the key line
    })
  );
  return (
    <animated.div {...bind()} style={{ padding: 40, background: "gold", x }}>
      Hello World
    </animated.div>
  );
}
```